# How to fix blank pages that are loaded in print preview in iPad? Can i delay print preview load?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, xamarin.ios

The html print document is loaded fine in the mobile app. When i click 'print document' and then printer option comes with the print preview, the second page comes empty. This is not always the case though. Without any code change, sometimes it loads, sometimes it doesn't. I am guessing it has to do something where the DOM elements are not fully loaded before showing print preview. Just an assumption .

Anyone knows how to fix it? Can i put a delay so that the DOM elements are creating before showing the print preview screen.

Ignore the first page. it has data in it. I have just covered it. Second page is coming empty. If i try reprinting after some time, the second page might load without any issue.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same problem. I'm sure it is not related with html. In my case, I print pdf file generated from UIView.